# list recursively all files and folders under the given path?

Tags: c#, .net, file, path, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recursively list all the files in a directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c)

I want to list the "sub-path" of files and folders for the giving folder (path)

let's say I have the folder C:\files\folder1\subfolder1\file.txt

if I give the function c:\files\folder1\

I will get
subfolder1
subfolder1\file.txt

Comment: You've examined the API available with FileInfo and DirectoryInfo?  Implementing the behavior you want is quite trivial with those classes...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DirSearch(@"c:\temp");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void DirSearch(string dir)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            Console.WriteLine(f);
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
            DirSearch(d);
        }

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 28):

You can use the  [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) method to list all files in a folder:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\files\folder1\", 
    "*.*",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Note that the `SearchOption` parameter can be used to control whether the search is recursive (`SearchOption.AllDirectories`) or not (`SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly`).

Comment: This solution does not include folders in the returned list.

Comment: @galmok: Use `Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(...)` instead of `Directory.GetFiles(...)` and `"*"` instead of `"*.*"`.

Answer (score 5):

```
String[] subDirectories;
String[] subFiles;
subDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("your path here");
subFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("your path here");
```

Comment: Really easy and it rocks. But to get only names -                foreach (String str in subDirectories)
                Console.WriteLine(str.Split('\\').Last());

            foreach (String str in subFiles)
                Console.WriteLine(str.Split('\\').Last());

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`System.IO.Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) class and [its methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory_methods.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I remember solving a similar problem not too long ago on SO, albeit it was in VB. Here's the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634798/avoid-system-volume-information-folder).